# Will there be a Reactive Cache API in Play

Tags: caching, playframework, reactive-programming, akka-stream, backpressure

We are having problems using [Play-Cache](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCache) in that the API is blocking. Are there any plans anyone knows of to come up with a new cache API in Play that is not only non-blocking, but reactive with back-pressure?

I've looked at [Play-Redis](https://github.com/KarelCemus/play-redis), but it does not seem to be fully non-blocking, and probably not reactive.

Answer (score 1):

Future plans are best discussed on the [Play](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/play-framework) or [Play dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/play-framework-dev) mailing lists.

That said, the default implementation for the Cache API is Ehcahe, which is a very mature JVM-only cache, but it is blocking.

If you need to prevent blocking on the the main Play thread pool, I suggest setting up a new thread pool to make the requests. This is a good bit of work on your side, but it is the same strategy as you would need in order to, say, work with the blocking JDBC API for databases.

Comment: We're torn between building our own API based on Futures/Streams, and working with the existing Play API. I'll see what people think on the mailing lists. Thanks for the tips. :-)

Comment: @Eric, best of luck!